# How do i solve Expo problem SDK 46 when i do eas update?

Tags: expo

i update my cli and the version of my app .

My expo go is now SDK 46 supported.

Before to do eas update, my app was working well on my phone.

Since that, i have this message when i try to do expo start and eas update with the public link

[image]

Do you think it could from an other package ?

this is also my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~46.0.7",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.2.0",
    "expo-cli": "6.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1275.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Expo config file in `app.json` or `app.config.js` specifies the correct `sdkVersion`.

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "sdkVersion": "46.0.0",  // I was missing this line
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `expo upgrade` in command line to update your SDK version. This same if you test on your phone, you need to update expo app on a store. Then you gotta have same SDK versions.